# Rails, how to create a scope where a habtm is populated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have user accounts that has a HABTM relationship to companies. Users can also have zero companies. I would like to write a scope where I only get users that belong to one or more companies. How can I accomplish this?

example model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  scope :independent,  # ????
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For no companies:

```
scope :independent, -> { where(:companies => []) }
```

for one or more companies:

```
scope :independent, -> { where("companies <> []") }
```